# Docker daemon wont start even after adding user/deleting host environment var etc

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04

I have been having trouble starting docker after installing it. I get the common error: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
There are many forums on stack overflow explaining solutions to this issue, however none of them have worked for me. I can not even connect with the docker daemon while running under sudo. I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling, deleting environment variables, and of course adding my user to the group/logging out. Can anyone help with this? Im running an ubuntu 14.04 vm on virtual box. Let me know what you all think and thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it running? If so, how (what command) did you run it?

Comment: Im not exactly sure if it is running. I can start it with sudo service docker start and it gives me a pid. However, if i do service docker status it says stopped/waiting

Comment: then its not running, when you `systemctl status -l docker` does it have any useful information/errors?